# A good source for WINAPI messages, message hierarchies, initialization routines

Tags: winapi, messaging

Does anyone know where can I find a good resource on WINAPI messages?

The information on MSDN has a very good document on each message alone, but the global picture is still foggy for me.

Say if I override WM_NCCALCSIZE to override the frame non-client area and extend the client area to whole window, who will take care of the close buttons and stuff? Who fire HITTESTS. In what order WM_SIZE, WM_CREATE, WM_ACTIVATE are fired? Are there any other messages that are good points to override the base functionality?

Every time I override a message like WM_SIZE, I always feel unsure if there are no other linked messages like WM_SIZING that have to be overrided as well. And I can't seem find a good document on the topic.

Comment: Using the Spy++ utility that comes with Visual Studio is a good way to see which messages are being sent to your window (or other windows) when things happen, and to see the order of messages. (Although if it isn't part of the documented API contract somewhere the OS could change things in the future, of course.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're heading for plain ole' Windows programming, I suggest you take a look at the canonical, classical book on the subject: [Programming Windows](http://www.charlespetzold.com/pw5/), from Charles Petzold.

IF you already know it, then take a good insight at MFC (Microsoft Foundation Classes), you can learn a lot from it.